# How can I update the UI of the button at the same time as I log out?

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-query, next.js14

How can I update the UI from dropdown menu to Login button at the same time as logout from Header component below?

stacks: next.js 14, typescript, tanstack/react-query

```
'use client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import logo from '@/public/assets/logo_250x250.png';
import { LogOut } from 'lucide-react';

import { useLogout } from '@/hooks/query/auth/useLogout';
import { useGetProfile } from '@/hooks/query/user/useGetProfile';

import { ROUTES_PATH } from '@/constants/routes';

import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
  Avatar,
  AvatarImage,
  AvatarFallback,
  Button,
} from '@/components/ui';

const Header = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const user = useGetProfile();
  const logout = useLogout();

  const handleClickLoginButton = () => {
    router.push(ROUTES_PATH.login);
  };

  const handleClickLogoutButton = () => {
    const ok = confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?');

    if (ok) {
      logout();
    }
  };

  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 w-screen flex items-center bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
      <div className="container flex justify-between items-center h-16 max-w-screen-2xl">
        <Link href="/">
          <button className="font-semibold text-xl">
            <Image src={logo} alt="home button" width={50} />
          </button>
        </Link>
        <div>
          {user ? (
            <DropdownMenu>
              <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
                <Button variant="link">
                  <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                    {' '}
                    <Avatar className="w-8 h-8">
                      <AvatarImage src={user.imageUrl} />
                      <AvatarFallback>Profile Image</AvatarFallback>
                    </Avatar>
                    <p>{user.nickname}</p>
                  </div>
                </Button>
              </DropdownMenuTrigger>
              <DropdownMenuContent>
                <DropdownMenuLabel>My Account</DropdownMenuLabel>

                <DropdownMenuSeparator />
                <DropdownMenuItem>Profile</DropdownMenuItem>

                <DropdownMenuSeparator />
                <DropdownMenuItem onClick={handleClickLogoutButton} className="justify-between items-center">
                  Log out <LogOut className="w-4 h-4 text-stone-500" />
                </DropdownMenuItem>
              </DropdownMenuContent>
            </DropdownMenu>
          ) : (
            <Button onClick={handleClickLoginButton} variant="outline">
              Login
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Please refer to the code useGetProfile and useLogout below.

```
// useGetProfile.ts
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { getProfile } from '@/api/user';

import { UserProfile } from '@/types/user';
import { QUERY_KEYS } from '@/constants/queryKeys';
import { getCookie } from '@/lib/cookie';
import { TOKEN_KEY } from '@/constants/token';

export const useGetProfile = () => {
  const hasToken = getCookie(TOKEN_KEY.ACCESS_TOKEN);
  const { data: user } = useQuery<UserProfile>({
    enabled: !!hasToken,
    queryKey: QUERY_KEYS.profile,
    queryFn: getProfile,
    staleTime: Infinity,
    retry: 1,
  });

  return user;
};
```

```
// useLogout.ts
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

import { removeToken } from '@/lib/token';

import { getLogout } from '@/api/auth';

import { TOKEN_KEY } from '@/constants/token';
import { ROUTES_PATH } from '@/constants/routes';

import { QUERY_KEYS } from '@/constants/queryKeys';
import { ToastSuccess } from '@/lib/toast';
import { TOAST_TEXT } from '@/constants/toastMessage/auth';

export const useLogout = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { mutate: logout } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: getLogout,
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: QUERY_KEYS.profile });

      removeToken(TOKEN_KEY.ACCESS_TOKEN);
      removeToken(TOKEN_KEY.REFRESH_TOKEN);

      ToastSuccess(TOAST_TEXT.SUCCESS_TO_LOGOUT);
      router.replace(ROUTES_PATH.main);
    },
  });

  return logout;
};
```

I've tried `queryClient.invalidateQueries`, but it hasn't been updated. I want to update it using react-query instead of using `useEffect`.

Comment: Can you show the `useGetProfile` code?